# Name of Font Style in Math Mode

Tags: math-mode, fonts

How can I generate the font style of the letter C in the following screenshot?

[image]

Comment: `\mathsf{C}` most likely

Comment: It looks very much like the capital C from the `eulervm` package.

Comment: @jasonhathcock That is it! Perfect, thank you for your help. Could you put this information in a formal answer, so that I can mark the question as answered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The character comes from the Euler fonts, which you can enable throughout using the `eulervm` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\begin{document}
{\em ...then $Q$ achieves capacity and the capacity of the DMC is equal to $\lambda$, i.e., 
\[C=I(Q,W)=\lambda.\]

\end{document}
```

[image: ![enter image description here]
Note: this changes all math characters.

If you want to imitate even more closely the style of the screenshot, so that the ordinary Computer Modern fonts are used, and the Euler fonts are specially invoked, say by `\mathsf`, you can omit using the entire `eulervm` package, and instead declare it in the document preamble this way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{U}{eur}{m}{n}
\begin{document}
{\em ...then $Q$ achieves capacity and the capacity of the DMC is equal to $\lambda$, i.e., 
\[\mathsf{C}=I(Q,W)=\lambda.\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for the help.